# Least resource-consuming Linux OS to run just Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, performance, distribution-choice, desktop-environment

I've developed some application which uses a browser in order to run. The usage of the browser is simply for the GUI which is built with html/css/js (there are lot of js animations). Currently, the application runs on a 2.1GHz CPU and 4GB of RAM.

I was looking for linux OS (based on debian/ubuntu) that will use the least amount of resources. After some research, I saw that there is Lubuntu and LXLE which both seems to be pretty efficient. However, the most ideal thing will be running something like Ubuntu Server and then install the least amount of packages in order to get Chrome working on it.

The OS I'm looking for is some OS that when it has loaded, it will use the least amount of resources as possible. For example, I have 2.1GHz CPU and 4GB RAM, when the OS has fully loaded, the OS will use about 2% of the CPU and MAX 300MB of RAM to "stay alive" which then will leave 3.7GB of ram and 98% of the CPU free for other tasks.

Another requirement is to be able to install Nginx, Mysql, PHP and some other small CLI components on the OS.

I want the single instance of web browser that will run to have **all** of the PC resources except to the OS system's resources.

Are there any distributions that can do this?

Comment: This is going to be hard to pin down unless you make you requirements very specific. At the moment it's either too broad or opinion based. You could try to edit and explain precisely what you need this distro to be able to do. What kind of resource usage is "light" for you? In the meantime, have a look at http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/ and http://puppylinux.org/

Comment: By "I want the single instance of web browser that will run to have all of the PC resources", do you mean you won't be running an X server on this system (perhaps running the X server on a remote system)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The server and the graphics has to be on the same machine to cut costs. What I mean is, all I need the OS to do is to actually let me run a web browser and queues. I just need to have a OS that consumes the least resources and frees all of the remaining resources to other applications that may need it. In this case, it will be an instance of some web browser.

Comment: @terdon I'm not sure what you mean by "too broad question" what other information do you need?

Comment: Basically, questions asking about "best distro for X" are not a good fit for the site. It comes down to opinion. Same goes for "lightest". You would need to edit and describe precisely what your minimum requirements are. This sort of thing is much better as a discussion in [chat] than as a question on the site. Did you check out the two distros I suggested?

Comment: @terdon I've edited the post. Hopes this is what you were looking for. I took a glance at your recommendations, hope you can re-consider them after reading my edit (to see if it's still answering the requirements).

Comment: I reopened it now that you made it more specific, thanks. I doubt anyone can answer though. You will probably have to try for yourself. DSL Linux claims to "Run light enough to power a 486DX with 16MB of Ram" though, so that should be fine for you.

Comment: @terdon I see. I've edit my post once again. I figured that another requirement would be to install Nginx, Mysql PHP and some other small CLI components on the server. Does DSL have that ability? (what package manager does it have?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution is mostly irrelevant here. You aren't at a scale where you need to squeeze every byte of memory and disk space.

The one part that can consume a lot of memory is the desktop environment. You don't need a fancy desktop environment to run a single application. In fact, you don't need a desktop environment at all: just a bare X server and a full-screen application. It's called a [kiosk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software). You can do this on any distribution.

So just pick Debian or Ubuntu or whatever you fancy as an administrator. And set it up for a kiosk. There are plenty of tutorials on the web, including pointers in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Seems to be exactly what I need. However, I read that making a kiosk out of Ubuntu Server is more resource friendly instead of making a kiosk out of Ubuntu Desktop. However, I could only find guides that shows how to create a kiosk from a Ubuntu Desktop. Do you have any resources that will show me how to do so from Ubuntu Server? (Explained in details if possible - chrome preferred)

Comment: @kfirba The only difference between Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop is the default set of installed packages. A tutorial for one works just as well for the other and there won't be any difference in performance since the end result will be the same.

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure that somewhere else I've read that in order to install web browser on Ubuntu server I will need to install some GUI packages? Also, if I get you right, if I do something like `apt-get install chrome` on Ubuntu server, will I be able to somehow launch it in my server without any additions?

Comment: @kfirba Install the `xserver-xorg` package to get a GUI. It's possible to run GUI applications on a machine without having a local display, if you only use a remote display, so the dependency management for Chrome will not mark a local GUI as required. It might install it nonetheless, because there may be a “recommended” dependency somewhere, but just make sure that `xserver-xorg` ends up installed and you'll be good.

Comment: I'm testing it right now. I just can't get it work. Also, even with when installing Ubuntu Server it seems like the server is running 88(!) processes, I think it's a lot. I simply installed a fresh new Ubuntu Server which i've downloaded from their website. Ran: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libexif12` but I still can't get chrome to run. When I try to run `chromium-browser` it says `Gtk: cannot open display` Any recommendations how to set this up properly?

Comment: @kfirba Are you sure it's 88 processes and not 88 threads? The kernel alone might have that many, depending on your hardware. To run Chrome, you need to start a GUI, it isn't enough to install it. If you're in a text mode console, run `startx` (which is from the `xinit` package, which I think is pulled in as a dependency, install it if it isn't) to start a session with the default desktop environment or window manager. See the tutorials for ways to make that session a minimal Chrome-only one.

Comment: I see. I'm using VirtualBox so for some reason the mouse doesn't work. Do you think there will be much difference in resource consumption by the OS if I used something like Lubuntu which comes with a very light GUI? Will be easier to set I think since I'm not a unix pro

Comment: @kfirba Lubuntu comes with a lighter default desktop environment than Ubuntu, but like the other variants, it only differs in the default configuration. If you make a kiosk, you won't be using LXDE anyway.

Comment: so for a starter like me, would you suggest jump right into a server and find out how to set a kiosk on it or use Lubuntu which will make it easier to configure because I won't need to mess with the GUI packages? BTW, do you happen to have any tutorial how to set a Ubuntu Server as a kiosk to get me started?